# Ruby enumerable reverse detect

Tags: ruby, arrays, ienumerable, reverse, detect

assuming I have the following array:

```
views = [
  { :user_id => 1, :viewed_at => '2012-06-29 17:03:28 -0400' },
  { :user_id => 1, :viewed_at => '2012-06-29 17:04:28 -0400' },
  { :user_id => 2, :viewed_at => '2012-06-29 17:05:28 -0400' },
  { :user_id => 3, :viewed_at => '2012-06-29 17:06:28 -0400' },
  { :user_id => 1, :viewed_at => '2012-06-29 17:07:28 -0400' },
  { :user_id => 1, :viewed_at => '2012-06-29 17:08:28 -0400' },
  { :user_id => 3, :viewed_at => '2012-06-29 17:09:28 -0400' },
  { :user_id => 3, :viewed_at => '2012-06-29 17:16:28 -0400' },
  { :user_id => 3, :viewed_at => '2012-06-29 17:26:28 -0400' },
  { :user_id => 3, :viewed_at => '2012-06-29 17:36:28 -0400' },
  { :user_id => 1, :viewed_at => '2012-06-29 17:47:28 -0400' },
  { :user_id => 2, :viewed_at => '2012-06-29 17:57:28 -0400' },
  { :user_id => 3, :viewed_at => '2012-06-29 17:67:28 -0400' },
  { :user_id => 1, :viewed_at => '2012-06-29 17:77:28 -0400' }
]
```

assuming the array is ordered by **viewed_at**

If I want to retrieve the last view hash in the **views** array for a particular **user_id**, I could do the following:

```
views.reverse.detect { |view| view[:user_id] == 1 }
```

where **detect** would returns first item in an enumerable where the block evaluates to true.

My question is:  I assume there is `O(n)` cost to the **reverse** method, so how can I detect in reverse without having to reverse the array?  Or is the **reverse** method not `O(n)`?

Comment: do you really have `17:77` as a time?

Comment: When you chain up methods, you always want to chain up enumerators. Enumerator chain only iterates the object once and is O(n). Most common example is `"hello".each_char.map{|x|x.succ}`

Comment: @texasbruce: that will be totally true with Ruby 2.0, where all kinds of lazy operations will be possible (now a lot of operations return arrays, not enumerators)

Comment: @tokland In 1.9, many returns enumerators already.

Comment: @texasbruce: how do you lazily do in 1.9 something as simple as `(1..10).map { |x| 2*x }.select { |x| x < 5 }`?

Comment: @tokland Many methods return enumerator without block, or return object with block.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn I created that array by hand and filled in numbers in order, the order was all I really cared about.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Method `Array#reverse` is O(n) in time and space. As you don't need the whole reversed array, you may use [Array#reverse_each](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-reverse_each), that would be O(1) in space. In practice, that's only relevant for really big arrays.

```
views.reverse_each.detect { |view| view[:user_id] == 1 }
#=> {:user_id=>1, :viewed_at=>"2012-06-29 17:77:28 -0400"}
```

Comment: this is very interesting.  I saw the reverse each method in the Ruby 1.9.3 Enumerable documentation, but its name implies that it iterates through each object in an enumerable.  I see by your example that it does't (potentially it could).  Would you mind explaining the difference between time an space in this context.  Thanks for your thoughtful answer!

Comment: "its name implies that it iterates through each object in an enumerable". `each` methods in Ruby are always lazy, they iterate the whole enumerable if asked to, but here it will stop when `detect` stops asking for more values. "Would you mind explaining the difference between time an space in this context". Using reverse_each: time) you potentially need to traverse the whole input to find the matching one, so it's linear O(n) in the worst case, space) you just need to accumulate the current element being checked, that's O(1). Examples in Python: http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: In a test against Ruby 2.5.1, code like this was not lazy.  To test it I set up a simple array and tried to detect the "3" in reverse order.    ar=[1,2,3,4,5]; ar.reverse_each{|v| puts "re to #{v}"}.detect{|v| v==3};    When I ran that code, it printed a line each of the five elements of the original array.  This suggests that either it is either generating some kind of intermediate, reversed version of the array or that the detect is not able to prematurely end the #reverse_each()

Comment: @DavidFoster. That's because you are sending a block to `reverse_each`, in this case the whole array must be iterated, of course. However, if you don't pass a block, it returns an `Enumerator` that will be iterated on demand.

Comment: @tokland - Thanks!  I didn't even notice that the block form of #reverse_each returns an Array rather than an enumerator.  I didn't not suspect that.

Answer (score 1):

This will get the index from the last object for which the block is true (or nil if none matches).

```
views.rindex{|view| view[:user_id] == 1}
```

After benchmarking @toklands `reverse_each` is (surprising for me) a lot faster:

```
require 'benchmark'
ar = Array.new(100){rand(100)}
target = rand(100)

Benchmark.bm(15) do |x|
  x.report('reverse_each'){1000.times{ar.reverse_each.detect(target)}}
  x.report('rindex'){1000.times{ar.rindex(target)}}
end


#                      user     system      total        real
#reverse_each      0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.002981)
#rindex            0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.012078)
```

Comment: that's surprising indeed, conceptually it's the same operation, the times should be very similar.